# UIButton connect to html <a href = "">

Tags: objective-c

Can the action of an objective c UIButton call a link from an html webpage? I set up a UIWebView to a certain url, and want the page to change automatically to a different url when a button is clicked on the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should only need these methods.

```
//First initialize the NSURLRequest.
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL
//Fire the request.
- (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

In your IBAction.

```
//In your IBAction
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURL]];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: in viewDidLoad: `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.loginpage.com"]]];`

then when button clicked: `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.logoutpage.com/"]]];`